# How do I store Excel File without getting the warning

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to replace my file but it gives me warning:

> The file already exists. Do you want to replace the file

In the code, I do not want the warning

Code:

```
    String fromFile = @"\\test.net\excel\123.xls";
    String toFile = @"\\test.net\excel\123.xls";

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(fromFile, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    File.Delete(toFile);

    wb.SaveAs(toFile, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    wb.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        app.Quit();
```

Comment: What does the warning say?

Comment: @Biscuits It says": The file already exists. Do you want to replace the file ?

Comment: Did you try the Save method, instead of SaveAs?

Comment: You're using Office Interop and ASP.NET. That's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @mason Why is it disastrous ? What other option do I have ?

Comment: @hellotemp8 Because Interop wasn't designed for server use, it's meant for environments with a GUI. So you're often going to get weird errors. [Microsoft says](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) not to use Interop on the server. Instead, you should ditch the `.xls` files and go with `.xlsx`, and use a library that is capable of reading and writing Office XML files `.xlsx` natively. Some libraries are EPPlus (my favorite), NPOI, and Open Office XML SDK (by Microsoft). I show some examples of this on [my blog](https://masonmcg.com/blog/entry/properly-generating-excel-files-in-net).

Comment: I have incorporated your error message into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
app.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

before the `SaveAs` call and add

```
app.DisplayAlerts = true;
```

after the `Close` event.